# ORA-12154 ONLY while running an integration test

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an integration test suite(which is a class library) and one of the tests connects to my DB and inserts records. However while doing do I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

My TNSNAMES etc are working just fine. I'm saying so because I have a console application which invokes the same line of code and it just works fine. It's able to retrieve and persist to the DB. Both the projects are in the same solution. As far as I could see, there is no paranthesis issue involved, I have checked the project path etc etc, and nothing noticable.

I'm triggering the test using Resharper debugger. I have a 64 bit machine with 32 bit oracle client installed.

To see why this was happening, I converted the class library (which has my integration test) into a console app, put in a main method and ran the same piece of code from the main, and it works.

I'm running the app/class lib on x86 configuration.

Any pointers on why this is happening?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most common error when using Oracle you will have make sure if you are using TNSNAMES.ORA file that the TNSNAMES is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)

Hope this helps else please see link for more help on it http://ora-12154.ora-code.com/